# Unable to apply begin - end boundary to nested if condition in mysql as like as in sql server

Tags: mysql, if-statement

when i tried nested if in mysql for example : (simplified the code for clarity)

```
if a = b
then
set i = 1;
    if c = d
    then 
       set j = k;
       set x = y;
    end if; --  when removed it works 
end if;
```

The above code throws error. When i tried the removing the commented line it works, but it seems like set x = y comes under the level 1 condition globally i.e (a = b) and does not specific to the level 2 condition (c = d). How to apply begin- end boundary as like as sql server in nested if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `THEN`:

```
if c = d
    then
    ...
```

[MySQL IF Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)

Comment: the object has invalid source text

Comment: actually im using dbForge studio. when i tried executing stored procedure it throws error as 'the object has invalid source text and cannot be saved'